# Built in help function

Tags: python, pycharm

I noticed that the "lookup" codes below doesn't return any thing:

```
    dir(str) 
    help(str)
```

Does anyone know what the right code to include in Pycharm that will return info on string help? I'm running Pycharm 3.4.1.

Comment: they work just fine for me, how are you using them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must print the results if you're not using the interactive python console.
You probably want:

```
print(dir(str))
```